# Using connect() from react-redux makes NavLinks from react-router not work?

Tags: react-router, react-redux

I'm learning redux and created a `Navbar` component that will handle user actions. It uses `NavLink` to add the 'active' class to my links so I can style the active link.  When I navigate my site however the active class doesn't move until I send an action to react (login/logout is all I"ve done so far).  If I take out the connect stuff and use the class component directly the `NavLinks` work fine.  Adding a log to `componentDidUpdate` shows that it isn't being called when connect is used.

Am I missing something?  I see there's [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) but I'm building a site for fun to learn the whole deal and I'm just starting to get redux, I don't want to bring in the concept of middleware and I definitely don't want to use `combineReducers` since at this point it would just mean having the router property and shoving everything else under something like 'main' in the state.

I'm thinking of using [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) and putting the whole redux state on it...

**update:** - I added react-router-redux and I can only get it to update on a route change if I add the new 'router' to my mapped props.

I have a `NavbarC` component class with a render method like this:

```
render() {
  let { props } = this;

  return <header className="navbar">
    <nav>
      <h1><NavLink to="/" exact>Home</NavLink></h1>
      <NavLink to="/friends">Friends</NavLink>
    </nav>
    <div></div>
    <div className="center-flex-row">
      { props.busy ? <section className="nav-right"><p>working<span className="spacer"></span><span className="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></span></p></section> :
        props.user ?
          <Logout onSignOutClick={props.onSignOutClick} user={props.user} /> :
          <Login onSignInClick={props.onSignInClick}/>
      }
    </div>
  </header>
}
```

And I use connect():

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { user: state.auth.user, busy: state.auth.busy
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSignInClick: () => {
      dispatch(userLogin());
    },
    onSignOutClick: () => {
      dispatch(userLogout());
    }
  }
}

const Logout = ({ user, onSignOutClick }) => {
  return <section className="nav-right">
    <button className="btn" onClick={ onSignOutClick }>Sign Out</button>
  </section>
}

const Login = ({ onSignInClick }) => {
  return <section className="nav-right">
    <button className="btn" onClick={ onSignInClick }>Sign In</button>
  </section>
}

export const Navbar = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavbarC)
```

Comment: What does your `dispatch` do ? Does it update correctly the state ?

Comment: That is working, it updates the state when the user logs in or out.  When that happens, the Navbar does update with the new `NavLink` highlighted, the problem is when just changing links it doesn't update because there are no different props, so connect is keeping the component from re-rendering.  The NavLinks must use the values from the context that are provided by react-router, and connect doesn't know or care if those change to prevent the component from re-rendering.

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work in three ways.  I think connect is ignoring the props by default and replacing them, the example I based my code on didn't use 'ownProps'.  So If I put the component in a route:

```
<Route path="/" component={Navbar}/>
```

And merge the properties in my `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log('mapping state:', state);
  console.log('  ownProps:', ownProps);
  return {
    user: state.main.auth.user,
    busy: state.main.auth.busy,
    ...ownProps
  }
}
```

That puts in the props from react-router (history, location, match) and causes the component to update because those values change when the route changes.

Another way is to bite the bullet and use `react-router-redux`, which puts a 'router' property on my state, which I then have to add to my `mapStateToProps`.  Even though I don't care about the value, connect will detect that the props are different and re-render the component:

```
let store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    main,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware),
}

// in Navbar.js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    user: state.main.auth.user,
    busy: state.main.auth.busy,
    router: state.router
  }
}
```

I can also specify `pure=false` in the [options](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to connect() and that should re-render my component every time (at least it updates the right NavLink when I change routes for sure):

```
export const Navbar = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, 
    undefined, { pure: false })(NavbarC)
```

Comment: Thanks you, I was wondering it too. The option `pure` did it !

Answer (score 5):

The best and easiest way to fix this issue is by doing

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, undefined, { pure: false })(NavbarC)
```

Comment: Eventough this seems to be the quickest solution and works, it would be nice to know what exactly those two last parameters are for and if there's any downsize about them?